# How do I send data from Raspberry Pi 3 python file to a Mobile Phone via BLE?

Tags: python, android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I actually have a python file on a Raspberry Pi 3 that contains Humidity and Temperature values. I have also a mobile app that's gonna use these values to apply an algorithm. I need to send the original values to the phone using Bluetooth. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: What is your question ? Please expand

Comment: I want to know how to send the values from the Raspberry Pi3 to the mobile phone using Bluetooth. I don't know if I should send it as a whole python file and then decrypt it on the mobile phone or if there is a method to send the values directly to the mobile phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BLE communication, devices generally don't exchange file. The center device e.g. the smartphone, discovers the services available on the peripheral device, and then it reads and/or write characteristics on the peripheral.

The firmware of your Raspberry Pi 3 should therefore provide a BLE service with a Humidity and Temperature characteristics. Your mobile app will then read these values from the device.

For a BLE overview:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le